# Rewrite code from Objective-C to conform with Swift power tools and concise style

Tags: ios, swift

I started a project with Objective-C and rewrote it with Swift. The project contains two `UITableViewController`s: *MasterViewController* and *DetailViewController*. *MasterViewController* is linked to *DetailViewController* with a segue.

*MasterViewController* has two `UITableViewCell`s. The cell with indexPath [0, 0] has a `detailTextLabel` that displays a `String`. Each time I click on this cell, I go to the *DetailViewController* which, in this case, displays a list of `String`s. The cell with indexPath [0, 1] has a `detailTextLabel` that displays an `Int`. Each time I click on this cell, I go to the *DetailViewController*, which in this case, displays a list of `Int`s.

Furthermore, when I select a cell in *DetailViewController*, it displays a checkmark and updates the *MasterViewController* related cell which triggered the segue.

Here is a picture of the different scenes of the project:

[image]

And here is my code:

**MasterViewController**

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myString = "Yellow"
    var myInt = 16

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "attributeChangeMethod:", name: "attributeChange", object: nil)
    }

    func attributeChangeMethod(notif: NSNotification) {
        if let passedString: AnyObject = notif.userInfo?["String"] {
            myString = passedString as String
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
        if let passedInt: AnyObject = notif.userInfo?["Int"] {
            myInt = passedInt as Int
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "attributeChange", object:nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "My string"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = myString
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "My int"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(myInt)"
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

        if sender as? UITableViewCell == tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) {
            controller.identifier = "String"
            controller.passedString = myString
        }
        if sender as? UITableViewCell == tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)) {
            controller.identifier = "Int"
            controller.passedInt = myInt
        }
    }

}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
class DetailViewController: UITableViewController {

    var identifier: String!
    var passedString: String!
    var passedInt: Int!
    var array: [Any]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if identifier == "String" {
            title = "Select My String"
            array = ["Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Red"]
        }
        if identifier == "Int" {
            title = "Select My Int"
            array = [8, 16, 32, 64]
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if identifier == "String" {
            cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row] as? String
            cell.accessoryType = (array[indexPath.row] as String) == passedString ? .Checkmark : .None
        }
        if identifier == "Int" {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(array[indexPath.row] as Int)"
            cell.accessoryType = (array[indexPath.row] as Int) == passedInt ? .Checkmark : .None
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells() as [UITableViewCell] {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        //Return the new value back to MasterViewController
        var dict: [String : AnyObject]!
        if identifier == "String" {
            passedString = array[indexPath.row] as? String
            dict = ["String" : array[indexPath.row] as String]
        }
        if identifier == "Int" {
            passedInt = array[indexPath.row] as? Int
            dict = ["Int" : array[indexPath.row] as Int]
        }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("attributeChange", object: nil, userInfo: dict)
    }

}
```

This code works fine but I have a problem: I don't like it. It doesn't look like Swift style modern code, it looks like a copy-paste from good old Objective-C to Swift. I dislike the fact to have an `identifier` property in *DetailViewController*: I always have to check `identifier` in `if` statements in order to perform actions. I also dislike the fact to have `passedString` and `passedInt` properties with one of them being `nil` in half of the cases. And, worst of it, I dislike the fact that `array` is of type `[Any]!`: it leads to many downcastings.

Is there any better way to write this code? Swift provides tools like gerenic structs and classes or protocol conformance type arrays. Can't they help write more proficient code here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem here isn't that your Swift looks like Objective-C.  The problem is that, because you're developing a toy app, you've used a toy design, and now you don't like the toy design.  Probably you followed a tutorial you found on the Internet (or even in Apple's docs), and most of those are for toy apps and toy designs.  In those tutorials, the author hates adding classes, and ends up littering `if` statements all over the code.  But [fewer classes does not necessarily lead to better design](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FearOfAddingClasses).

Here's how I would design this app as if it were **not** a toy.  Notice that in the design below, there are almost no `if` statements.  In serious apps, I try to rely on message dispatch to choose the code path.

### Objective-C

I know your question was about Swift, but I'll start with Objective-C to demonstrate that the problem is with the toy design, not the language choice.

First, let's create a real model layer.  We have a master model, which is an array of details:

#### MasterModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MasterModel : NSObject

/** An array of `DetailModel`. */
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *details;

@end
```

and we have a detail model:

#### DetailModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DetailModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSArray *options;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger selectedOptionIndex;

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title options:(NSArray *)options;

@end
```

In a real app, you'd probably load the model from a database or a file.  In this toy app, I'll hard-code it:

#### MasterModel.m

```
#import "MasterModel.h"
#import "DetailModel.h"

@implementation MasterModel

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _details = @[ [self newStringDetailModel], [self newIntDetailModel] ];
    }
    return self;
}

- (DetailModel *)newStringDetailModel {
    NSArray *options = @[ @"Yellow", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Red" ];
    return [[DetailModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"My String" options:options];
}

- (DetailModel *)newIntDetailModel {
    NSArray *options = @[ @8, @16, @32, @64 ];
    return [[DetailModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Int" options:options];
}

@end
```

#### DetailModel.m

```
#import "DetailModel.h"

@implementation DetailModel

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title options:(NSArray *)options {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _title = [title copy];
        _options = [options copy];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now we need a master view controller to display the master model:

#### MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MasterModel;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MasterModel *model;

@end
```

#### MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "MasterModel.h"
#import "MasterCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    _model = [[MasterModel alloc] init];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

The master table view shows one row per detail model in the master model:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _model.details.count;
}
```

I use a custom cell class for each row.  I just hand the cell its model and the cell takes care of the details:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MasterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detail" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.model = _model.details[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

In a real app, you might have many segues, so we dispatch to another method based on the segue identifier:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        [self prepareForShowDetailSegue:segue sender:sender];
    }
}
```

Because each master cell knows which detail model it's displaying, we can just ask the cell for its model and hand that off to the detail view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForShowDetailSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DetailViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    MasterCell *cell = sender;
    destination.model = cell.model;
}

@end
```

#### MasterCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailModel;

@interface MasterCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) DetailModel *model;

@end
```

#### MasterCell.m

```
#import "MasterCell.h"
#import "DetailModel.h"

@implementation MasterCell
```

Remember that cells can be reused.  In this app, they won't be (because there are only going to be two instances of `MasterCell` and they fit on the screen together), but this is the general pattern I follow when I expect cell reuse:

```
- (void)setModel:(DetailModel *)model {
    [self disconnectFromModel];
    _model = model;
    [self connectToModel];
    [self update];
}

- (void)update {
    if (self.model != nil) {
        self.textLabel.text = self.model.title;
        self.detailTextLabel.text = [self.model.options[self.model.selectedOptionIndex] description];
    }
}
```

When the user goes into the detail view and changes the selected option, the master cell for that detail needs to be updated.  We'll use key-value observing (KVO) to detect the change to the selection.

```
static char kSelectedOptionIndexContext;

- (void)disconnectFromModel {
    [self.model removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedOptionIndex" context:&kSelectedOptionIndexContext];
}
```

Note that if `self.model` was nil (as it will be the first time the cell is used), the above method has no effect, and if we were to set the model back to `nil`, the below method would have no effect.

```
- (void)connectToModel {
    [self.model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedOptionIndex" options:0 context:&kSelectedOptionIndexContext];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == &kSelectedOptionIndexContext) {
        [self update];
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Generally it's important to deregister observers when they are deallocated.  Otherwise, you will crash if the observed property changes later.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self disconnectFromModel];
}

@end
```

#### DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailModel;

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) DetailModel *model;

@end
```

#### DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "DetailModel.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
```

Since we don't reuse `DetailViewController` instances, and `DetailViewController` doesn't use KVO, `setModel:` is simpler:

```
- (void)setModel:(DetailModel *)model {
    _model = model;
    self.navigationItem.title = [@"Select " stringByAppendingString:_model.title];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _model.options.count;
}
```

In this case, I don't need to store a model reference in the table view cell, and I can get away with just using a generic `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"option" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_model.options[indexPath.row] description];
    if (_model.selectedOptionIndex == indexPath.row) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *priorSelectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_model.selectedOptionIndex inSection:0]];
    priorSelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    _model.selectedOptionIndex = indexPath.row;
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

@end
```

### Swift

Now let's use Swift to implement this design.  The model is pretty much the same:

#### MasterModel.swift

```
import UIKit

class MasterModel: NSObject {

    let details: Array<DetailModel>

    override init() {
        details = [ MasterModel.newStringDetailModel(), MasterModel.newIntDetailModel() ]
        super.init()
    }

    private class func newStringDetailModel() -> DetailModel {
        return DetailModel(title: "My String", options: [ "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Red" ])
    }

    private class func newIntDetailModel() -> DetailModel {
        let options: Array<Printable> = [ 8, 16, 32, 64 ]
        return DetailModel(title: "My Int", options:options)
    }

}
```

#### DetailModel.swift

```
import UIKit

class DetailModel: NSObject {

    let title: String
    let options: Array<Printable>
    dynamic var selectedOptionIndex: Int

    init(title: String, options: Array<Printable>) {
        self.title = title
        self.options = options
        self.selectedOptionIndex = 0
    }

}
```

I've actually cheated a bit by using `Printable` as the array element type (and by relying on `NSObject` as the array element type in the Objective-C version).  In a real app, I'd probably create my own class hierarchy for the different option types, or at least add categories to `NSString` and `NSNumber` to format them appropriately instead of relying on the `description` provided by `Printable`/`NSObject`.

#### MasterViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    let model = MasterModel()

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.details.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detail", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MasterCell
        cell.model = model.details[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ShowDetail") {
            prepareForShowDetailSegue(segue, sender:sender)
        }
    }

    private func prepareForShowDetailSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        let cell = sender! as MasterCell
        destination.model = cell.model
    }

}
```

#### MasterCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class MasterCell: UITableViewCell {

    var model: DetailModel? {
        willSet {
            disconnectFromModel()
        }
        didSet {
            connectToModel()
            update()
        }
    }
```

What follows is actually the trickiest part in the Swift implementation, because of KVO.  The `context` argument to KVO methods is a `void *` in Objective-C and an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` in Swift.  I found that it doesn't work unless I explicitly create an `UnsafeMutablePointer` instance, rather than relying on Swift's `&` operator, which converts to `UnsafeMutablePointer` in some circumstances.

Also, I would make this a class variable, but the compiler doesn't support those “yet”.

```
    // Swift doesn't support class variables yet.
    private lazy var selectedOptionIndexContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.alloc(1)

    private func disconnectFromModel() {
        model?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedOptionIndex", context: selectedOptionIndexContext)
    }

    private func connectToModel() {
        model?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedOptionIndex", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: selectedOptionIndexContext)
    }

    private class func toUnsafeMutablePointer(p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> {
        return p
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if (context == selectedOptionIndexContext) {
            update()
        } else {
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

    private func update() {
        if (model != nil) {
            textLabel?.text = model?.title;
            detailTextLabel?.text = (model?.options[model!.selectedOptionIndex])?.description
        }
    }
```

Note that, to avoid a memory leak, we need to explicitly deallocated any KVO contexts we created.

```
    deinit {
        disconnectFromModel()
        selectedOptionIndexContext.dealloc(1)
    }

}
```

#### DetailViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UITableViewController {

    var model: DetailModel? {
        didSet {
            navigationItem.title = "Select " + model!.title
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model!.options.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("option", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = model!.options[indexPath.row].description
        if (model!.selectedOptionIndex == indexPath.row) {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let priorSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: model!.selectedOptionIndex, inSection: 0))
        priorSelectedCell?.accessoryType = .None
        model!.selectedOptionIndex = indexPath.row
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        selectedCell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }

}
```

I've uploaded both versions to [this github repository](https://github.com/mayoff/intStringDetails).

Comment: Wow, what an answer! - One question though: I cannot see where the `private class func toUnsafeMutablePointer` is used, and your code seems to work without it. Is that really needed?

Comment: It isn't necessary.  It is a vestige of an evolutionary dead end.

Comment: I'm speechless. Great explanation. Great Objective-C / Swift code. I even laughed reading your answer ("toy design", big lol). But now I have hope: we can do better code for even simple things. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer, but passing the model to the master table view cell violates MVC. I would expose description and option properties with setters that set the textLabel and detailTextLabel titles. The MasterViewController then sets those properties. This keeps the knowledge of the model away from the view (the table cell). I'd go further and use a custom detail cell too with properties that the VC uses. That would hide the implementation details of using textLabel and accessory views from the VC. More code, but less coupling and better separation of concerns.

Comment: Some people think the view shouldn't read the model directly.  Some people think it should.  I am in the latter group.  I don't want “MVC” to stand for “Massive View Controller”.  There's going to be custom code to adapt the app-specific model to generic views; whether that code should live in the controller, an app-specific custom view, or some other object is a matter of opinion, taste, and debate.

Comment: @robmayoff, I like your code, with the exception of `update()` in MasterCell. You check for nil on model `if (model != nil)`, then use optional chaining anyways. I would replace this with `if let theModel = model` and refer to `theModel` without chaining with `?` or `!`.