# Road to MVC: the case of Settings Table View Controller

Tags: swift, mvc, ios, cocoa

Now that I know that [MVC can help do better code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62964/53113), I want to make my `SettingsTableViewController` class conform to it.

`SettingsTableViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. It is linked to a storyboard scene that contains a `UITableView` with two cells (grouped tableView style, prototype cells). The first cell has a right detail style (textLabel and detailTextLabel), the second cell has a custom style and displays a `UIPickerView` inside of its contentView.

When it appears on screen, `SettingsTableViewController` displays only the first cell. When I click on this cell, the second cell containing a `UIPickerView` appears. If I click again on the first cell, the second cell disappears.

The detailtextLabel of the first row displays an integer saved in `NSUserDefaults`. The pickerView of the second cell is linked to an array of integers. When I select a row in the pickerView, it saves the row's related integer in `NSUserDefaults` and updates the detailtextLabel of the first cell.

The image below may help understand the way it works:

[image]

Before knowing the concept of MVC, I was able to write the following code to make the previous explanation work:

```
class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    let itemsArray = [5, 10, 15]
    var pickerIndexPath: NSIndexPath? //acts like a Bool and allows to hide or show cell with identifier "pickerCell"
    var numberOfItems: Int {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("NumberOfItems")
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(newValue, forKey: "NumberOfItems")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Settings"

        //Init numberOfItems
        if numberOfItems == 0 {
            numberOfItems = 5
        }

        //Autoset cells height (iOS8)
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //If pickerIndexPath is nil, show only one cell
        return pickerIndexPath == nil ? 1 : 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RightDetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Items"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(numberOfItems)"
        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PickerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .None

            //Set pickerView inside cell
            let picker = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UIPickerView
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.dataSource = self

            //Set the middle row in picker according to numberOfItems
            if let index = find(itemsArray, numberOfItems) {
                picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        switch indexPath {
        case NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0):
            return nil
        default:
            return indexPath
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        if indexPath == NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0) {
            //Show or hide pickerCell
            if pickerIndexPath == nil {
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                pickerIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([pickerIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            } else {
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([pickerIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                pickerIndexPath = nil
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: UIPickerViewDataSource
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return itemsArray.count
    }

    //MARK: UIPickerViewDelegate
    func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return "\(itemsArray[row]) items"
    }

    func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerIndexPath != nil {
            //save new value in NSUserDefaults
            numberOfItems = itemsArray[row]

            //update first cell
            let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: pickerIndexPath!.row - 1, inSection: 0)
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([index], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Then, in order to conform to MVC design pattern, I replaced the previous code with the following:

**SettingsTableViewController:**

```
class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let dataSource = DataSource()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Settings"

        //Autoset cells height (iOS8)
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //If pickerIndexPath is nil, show only one cell
        return dataSource.pickerIndexPath == nil ? 1 : 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LabelCell
            cell.dataSource = dataSource
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PickerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PickerCell
            cell.dataSource = dataSource
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        switch indexPath {
        case NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0):
            return nil
        default:
            return indexPath
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        if indexPath == NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0) {
            //Show or hide pickerCell
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            if dataSource.pickerIndexPath == nil {
                dataSource.pickerIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: 0)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([dataSource.pickerIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            } else {
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([dataSource.pickerIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                dataSource.pickerIndexPath = nil
            }
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

**LabelCell:**

```
//Global context variable
private var observerContext = 0

class LabelCell: UITableViewCell {

    var dataSource: DataSource? {
        willSet {
            disconnectFromModel()
        }
        didSet {
            connectToModel()
            update()
        }
    }


    private func disconnectFromModel() {
        dataSource?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "numberOfItems", context: &observerContext)
    }

    private func connectToModel() {
        dataSource?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "numberOfItems", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: &observerContext)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if context == &observerContext {
            update()
        } else {
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }

    }

    private func update() {
        if let model = dataSource {
            textLabel?.text = "Items"
            detailTextLabel?.text = "\(model.numberOfItems)"
        }
    }

    deinit {
        disconnectFromModel()
    }

}
```

**PickerCell:**

```
class PickerCell: UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    var dataSource: DataSource? {
        didSet {
            update()
        }
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        selectionStyle = .None
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
    }

    func update() {
        if let dataSource = dataSource {
            if let index = find(dataSource.itemsArray, dataSource.inspectionPref) {
                picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: UIPickerViewDataSource
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource!.itemsArray.count
    }

    //MARK: UIPickerViewDelegate
    func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return "\(dataSource!.itemsArray[row]) items"
    }

    func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        dataSource!.numberOfItems = dataSource!.itemsArray[row]
    }

}
```

**DataSource:**

```
class DataSource: NSObject {

    let itemsArray = [5, 10, 15]
    var pickerIndexPath: NSIndexPath? //allows to hide or show cell with identifier "pickerCell"
    dynamic var numberOfItems: Int {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("NumberOfItems")
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(newValue, forKey: "NumberOfItems")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }


    override init() {
        super.init()

        //Init numberOfItems at first launch
        if numberOfItems == 0 {
            numberOfItems = 5
        }
    }

}
```

I have several questions about this new code. As it is my first attempt with MVC, I wonder if it is a real MVC design pattern code. I also ask myself if it is a complete/correct MVC code: is there anything left to do/modify in order to fully conform to MVC? Furthermore, I've read that passing a model to a view (here, a cell) is not recommended. Thus, what would be the way to make a cell interact with the model without passing the model to it?

Comment: About passing a model to the view; usually it's recommended to pass a ViewModel instead of a DataModel. Essentially, they're simple models that only have data needed by the view. You would strip fields that are not needed, and you can compose multiple data models into one view model, specific to your view. At least, that's how I understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I can hardly translate it to real code. The truth is that it's easy to find theoretical answers about MVC and MVVM but really hard to find practical answers. Since Swift has been launched, I've only been able to find two MVC/MVVM concrete explanations for it (the [Rob Mayoff's answer to a previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62964/53113) and a [Natasha The Robot blog post](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-mvvm-optionals/)). Would you give a try for this question?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Swift at all, which is why I only left a comment, hoping to give you a little advice.

Comment: @IvoCoumans viewmodel is equivalent of controller in the pattern of MVVM, it's definitely different from model, so I don't agree with your point of passing some view model to controller.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Swift at all. but still want to add some comments.

the primary goal of design pattern of "MVC" is to separate the aspects involved, so that extension and modification can be done easily. so yes MVC definitely involves "MODEL" "VIEW" "CONTROLLER". but as you might know it has several mutations: MVVM,MTV(in the case of Django framework). The key is along the directions of separation you made something like that, but I myself don't get bureaucratic about that, as long as I think the refactoring made the whole process much clear, I am okay with my "MVC".

In the case of your refactoring, I am seeing a bit chunk of logic separated into controllers, views, models. which is good enough for me in terms of "MVC".

Comment: I generally go follow this wisdom, `<jiggliemon> MVD, Model View Don't ask`